# DataGridView updating every 1 second but vertical scrollbar not showing properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have developed a application where the dataGridView is updated around every second. I am enabling both the scroll bars. The  vertical scroll bar buttons down and up is not showing. I am not able to scroll through vertical scrollbar. Also if I enable to show last row as first scrolling index application hangs.

When I run the application in Visual Studio environment it works fine. Only when I execute outside visual studio environment then I observe this behavior.

Please find below Grid Update code.

```
private static void UpdateGrid(DataTable table)
{
    JSONTest form = (JSONTest)Application.OpenForms["JSONTest"];
    if (form.GridTestReport.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateGridThreadHandler handler = UpdateGrid11;
        form.GridTestReport.BeginInvoke(handler, table);
    }
    else
    {                
        form.GridTestReport.DataSource = table;           
    }
}

private static void UpdateGridView()
{
    JSONTest form = (JSONTest)Application.OpenForms["JSONTest"];
    if (form.GridTestReport.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateGridViewCallback d = new UpdateGridViewCallback(UpdateGridView);
        form.GridTestReport.Invoke(d);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form.GridTestReport.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "FAIL")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            row.Cells["RowNumber"].Value = row.Index + 1;
        }
        //if (form.GridTestReport.RowCount > 5)
        //{
        //    form.GridTestReport.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = form.GridTestReport.RowCount - 1;
        //}                

        form.lbl_Response.Text = "Received Response :" + TestSuitADU.countReceivedResponse.ToString();
        form.lbl_Request.Text = "Sent Request:" + RandomExecution.CountRequest.ToString();
        if (form.TestClasses_combox.SelectedItem == "Batch")
        {
            form.lbl_Request.Text = "Sent Request:" + TestSuitADU.CountRequestResponse.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```